# Bootstrap drop-down add check icon when submenu is selected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap dropdown menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/bs5rc6k3/

[image]

How can I add an icon to the selected drop-down menu option and set its class as `selected`? When clicking a new option that option will be selected.

The icon is this font-awesome one: `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bs5rc6k3/3/)

JS:

```
$('#myDropdown > li > a').click(function(e){
    $('#myDropdown > li > a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected'); 
});
```

CSS (to hide the check unless it is within a 'selected' element):

```
#myDropdown > li > a > .fa{
    visibility:hidden;
}
#myDropdown > li > a.selected > .fa{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <!-- added an ID for the javascript -->
    <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
             <a href="#">
                 <i class="fa fa-check"></i> 
                 <span class="search-option">Option 1</span>
             </a>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-check "></i> 
                  <span class="search-option">Option 2</span>
             </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: :) glad to be able to help